# The Connotation of an "Algebra"

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, soft-question

I am studying some real analysis as we speak, currently on the topic of function spaces. In particular, this section of my book is discussing function algebras. I have heard of other types of algebras, such as $\sigma-$algebras, Kac-Moody algebras, operator algebras etc.

My question is simple: Intuitively, when I hear "______ algebra", what should I think of? That is, what kind of structure is an algebra- what is the connotation of the word? Is it generally any type of algebraic structure?

Comment: Probably the concept of an algebra over a field.

Comment: A $\sigma$ algebra is certainly not an example of an algebra over a field...

Comment: Divorce the idea of "$\sigma$-algebra" from the other notions of algebra. I always thought it was badly named. Most of the usages of the term "algebra" are things where addition and multiplication is defined, and addition makes the set an abelian group. Often they have other structure (such as a vector space structure over a field.) Some "algebras" have non-associative multiplication; certainly, it need not be commutative. But it is a sort of moving target - "Universal algebras" are very general, for example. Basically, it is a word like "number" which is used somewhat sloppily.

Comment: I see. So it is difficult to develop an intuition in this case.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: $\sigma$-alebras are, however, special cases of _Boolean_ algebras.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews A $\sigma$-algebra is a vector space over the field with two elements $\Bbb Z_2$ if we define the sum of two sets to be their symmetric difference and define scalar multiplication by $0\cdot A = \emptyset$ and $1\cdot A = A$. If we further define the product of two sets to be their intersection then it is an algebra over the field $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: @ZoeH Yes, I realize this, but the fundamental property - countable joins - is not representable in a standard algebraic sense.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein A $\sigma$-algebra  **is** an $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebra with symmetric difference as addition and intersection as multiplication.  That's where the name comes from!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general **an** algebra means

> a structure with one or more binary operations satisfying certain rules, but where those rules didn't get one of the fancy names like "ring" or "field" because they ran out of good words before this *particular* set of rules were first considered.

Many kinds of algebras belong to a narrower group,

> something that is either a vector space or a module over some ring, and which *additionally* has a binary operation that distributes over the vector/module addition and can -- to some extent -- be thought of as a "multiplication" operation.

But the only way to be sure that what you're looking at belongs to this narrower concept is to look at the definition, so that is not *really* helpful.

Comment: I disagree with the use of the adjective binary -- many types of algebra have unary and nullary operations, and some very important types of algebras have $(\ge 3)$-ary operations and are still called "algebras". See e.g. unital associative algebra (AKA rings), or BV-algebras, or $A_\infty$-algebras...